# How may I update a JTextField while my GUI is running?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouselistener

So this is the class with the text field

```
public class SeatInformation extends JPanel{


 public static byte section = 0;
 public static int price = 0;
 public static char row = 0;
 public static byte number = 0;

public SeatInformation(String title){


    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5)); 
     setLocation(500,20);
     setSize(100, 50); 



     //Section Label and TextField
    JLabel SectionLabel = new JLabel("Section:");
    SectionLabel.setVisible(true);
    add(SectionLabel); 

    JTextField Section = new JTextField(""+section);
    Section.setVisible(true);
    add(Section);
```

And here is my code to call a change in the field.

```
if(Stadium.getSeat(r,c).getSection() == 1){

                final byte s = Stadium.getSeat(r,c).getSection();
                final int p = Stadium.getSeat(r, c).getPrice();
                final char ro = Stadium.getSeat(r, c).getRow();
                final byte n = Stadium.getSeat(r, c).getNumber();


            re.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){ 
                    SeatInformation.section = s;

                } 
                });
```

I do not know how to update all the values inside my "SeatInformation" Class, all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: As a note, Java convention is to use lowercase initial letters for variable names. Since you already have a `section` variable, the standard approach would be to declare a variable like `JTextField sectionField`.

Comment: 1) Is there a reason that are you extending JPanel? Are you adding functionality ?? 2) Why do you use static variable? You wan to share that values with all SeatInformation instances? 3) You don't have to call `textfield.setVisible` or `label.setVisible` they are visible by default 4) follow java code conventions

Answer (score 2):

You would have to save the instance of your JTextField in an attribute of your class and call `setText()`